# Can't bind barby html_outputter output using knockout html binding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, knockout.js, rubygems, barcode

I am using html_outputter of rails barby gem to generate barcode. The generated in html & I am trying to bind this with knockout html binding to my print_view page. But it doesn't show my barcode.

Html Code:

```
<div id="barcode-table" data-bind="html: barcode_html" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

Barby html_outputter Output:

```
<table class="barby-barcode"><tbody><tr class="barby-row"><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell off"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td><td class="barby-cell on"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problem in the code. I need to enable graphics option from more settings of my browsers print_viewer.